# PHP: Why do people hate globals?

Tags: php, global-variables

If you enter `global` into Google, the first PHP-related page will surely be about how globals are evil. Why is this so? I have been using them in a lot of my functions and classes and have never had any problems.

Comment: Are you sure that first PHP-related page doesn't offer any sort of explanation as to *why* globals are evil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first attempt to google 'php global' brought me this:
http://tjhunt.blogspot.de/2009/04/php-global-variables-are-not.html

Answer (score 1):

You may google "why global is evil?" as well.

One of the first results: [On stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)